# PHP If dentro de un HTML

Tags: php, html

No acabo de comprender como funcionan las comillas en HTML y PHP. Alguien me podria ayudar a comprender su funcionamiento?

Por ejemplo, tengo el siguiente div:

```
<div class="" style="background-image: url(/uploads/{{$category->image_path}}/t_{{$category->image}});"></div>
```

Si yo ahora quiero poner un if dentro del background-image, para que controle si la $category->image es nula, que el background sea una imagen por defecto, como seria?

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
<div class="" style="background-image: {{(is_null($category->image)) ? url(/uploads/{{$category->image_path}}/t_{{$category->image}}) : url(/uploads/categories/t_default_category.png))}};"></div>
```

Comment: Esto no es HTML + PHP, es el formato de algún motor o procesador de plantillas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar esta forma:

```
<? if ($condition): ?>
  <p>Content</p>
<? elseif ($other_condition): ?>
  <p>Other Content</p>
<? else: ?>
  <p>Default Content</p>
<? endif; ?>
```

También puedes usarlo dentro de un propio elemento html:

```
<div class=<? if($condition): ?>"class_1"<? else: ?>"class_2"<? endif; ?>
```

En tu caso en concreto sería:

```
<div 
     class="" 
     style="background-image:<? if($condition) ?> url(url_1) <? else: ?> url(url_2) <? endif; ?>"
>
</div>
```

Comment: Podrias ya que estas darme mi codigo en el segundo formato? Porque lo he intentado y no funciona

Answer (score 3):

Mezclar bloques PHP/HTML produce un código confuso y difícil de analizar/depurar.

En tu caso yo trabajaría siempre de un solo bloque PHP concatenando en una variable.

La idea de concatenar te permite implementar mejor la lógica del código, usando ternarios por ejemplo.

```
$html="";
if ($condicion) {
    $html.="<div class=\"\" style=\"background-image: url(/uploads/{$category->image_path}/t_{$category->image});\"></div>";
} else {
    $html.="<p>Otro contenido</p>";
}
echo $html;
```

Supongamos un escenario donde la clase del `div` debería ser `default` cuando un elemento esté vacío, podrías hacerlo incluso sin necesidad de un `if`, mediante el operador de fusión de null o un operador ternario.

Por ejemplo:

```
#Objeto de prueba
$category = new stdClass();
$category->image = 'existe';

#Definimos cuál será la clase con fusión de null
$theClass=$category->image ?? "default";
$html="<div class=\"$theClass\">";
echo $html;
```

**Salida:**

```
<div class="existe">
```

Veamos qué ocurre si no existiera:

```
#Objeto de prueba, ahora sin la propiedad image
$category = new stdClass();
$category->other = 'existe';

$theClass=$category->image ?? "default";
$html="<div class=\"$theClass\">";
echo $html;
```

**Salida:**

```
<div class="default">
```

En conclusión, casi siempre es mejor trabajar dentro de un solo bloque PHP. Las ventajas son:

- Claridad en el código
- Mayor facilidad de depurar
- Mayor facilidad para adaptar el código a evoluciones, por ejemplo un futuro uso de plantillas
- Mayor posibilidad de usar con toda libertad las ventajas que ofrece el lenguaje (como el uso del operador de fusión de null que he usado más arriba)

No obstante, si en algún contexto tuvieras un bloque grande de sólo HTML sí podrías ponerlo directamente.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que pintar la condición dentro de `<# condicion #>` para tu código yo probaría lo siguiente:

```
<# if ( $category->image != null ) { #>
  <div class="" style="background-image: url(/uploads/{{$category->image_path}}/t_{{$category->image}});"></div>
<# } #>
```

Comment: Eso funciona, pero la idea era entender como puedo usar el if dentro del objeto html

Comment: La forma es esa, para utilizar las condiciones tienes que incluirlo dentro de <#  #>

Comment: No, me refiero dentro del propio elemento html. Yo he visto mucha gente usarlo como yo lo estaba haciendo, pero en particular en mi caso, me daba problemas por alguna propiedad de las comillas ("") que no entiendo...